# MVVM pattern - public methods and properties meant only for the View

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, mvvm

With the MVVM pattern, I make the methods and properties the View binds to as public.

It feels like these should only be public for the view, and not anywhere else. Almost like a protected concept. But also, you want some public methods that can be used by other classes, so it gets kind of muddled.

I'm writing TypeScript so I could really access whatever methods/properties I wanted to, but in a language like C# I would guess you would *have to* expose viewodel properties as public for the view and truly have this issue.

ViewModel:

```
class viewModel {
  private mode = "Editable";
  // this is only meant for the view. but it's public so it could be tampered with.
  public items = ko.observableArray();
  // this is meant to be used by other code.
  public setMode(mode) {
    this.mode = mode;
  }
  private _datasvc = new someDataService();
  constructor() {
    this.items = this._datsvc.getItems();
  }
}
```

Am I just not understanding or using MVVM correctly?

Comment: Really, really don't waste your time hiding data in this situation.  You're not gaining any benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I just not understanding or using MVVM correctly?

In MVVM core concepts the view model exposes stuff that can be changed by the view. So hiding this is not something *dictated by MVVM*.

That said, things are either public or private. With `public` you get read write.

What you can do is use a `getter` but be careful as the underlying array might still be a *reference*, so you would want to clone it, but that is a significant performance hit + deep immutability might not be guaranteed unless you clone the *items* in the array as well.